# Action on the previous view controller after a dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have two view controllers. By pressing button1, I change from VS_1 to VS_2. By pressing button2, I go to the view controller_1. I need button1 to change its color to red at this moment. How to do it?

```
class VC_1: UIViewController{

    ..........
    var button1 = UIButton()
    button1.backgroundColor = .green

    @IBAction func goToVC_2(_ sender: Any) {

        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vC2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2") as! VC_2

        self.present(vC2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class VC_2: UIViewController{

    ..........
    var button2 = UIButton()
    button2.backgroundColor = .green

    @IBAction func goToVC_1(_ sender: Any) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can't you change the color last in goToVC_2?

Comment: Make a delegate call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using Delegates like this:

FirstViewController:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, BackButtonDelegate {
 
    @IBOutlet weak var goVC2ButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    
    func onBackButtonClicked(firstButtonColor: UIColor) {
        self.goVC2ButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = firstButtonColor
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
         if segue.identifier == "goSecondVC" {
             let secondVC: SecondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
             secondVC.delegate = self
         }
     }
}
```

SecondViewController:

```
import UIKit

protocol BackButtonDelegate {
    func onBackButtonClicked(firstButtonColor: UIColor)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var delegate: BackButtonDelegate? = nil
    
    @IBAction func goVC1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if self.delegate != nil {
            let colorToBeSetOnButtonFromFirstVC = UIColor.red // here you set what color you want
            self.delegate?.onBackButtonClicked(firstButtonColor: colorToBeSetOnButtonFromFirstVC)
            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by Callback, Delegate etc.

By callback:

```
@IBAction func goToVC_2(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vC2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2") as! VC_2

    vC2.didTapButton = {
        // change color here 
    }
    self.present(vC2, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

```
var didTapButton: () -> Void = { }

@IBAction func goToVC_1(_ sender: Any) {
    didTapButton()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Note that in UIKit it's the responsibility of the presenting view controller to dismiss the view controller that it presented. So the dismiss should be called by  VC1, in the line where it says "change color here"